# How to return the tkinter button pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to something like this:

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4]
for x in range(len(list)):
    hi = tk.Button(command = lambda: function)
def function():
    print(list[x])
```

The problem is `x` is always `5` so it always prints `4`, I want it to print the corresponding value. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Binding an argument default (as in the duplicate) with get you separate values bound for each `lambda`.

Comment: You'll also have to modify the `def function` to accept the argument value that will now be passed (instead of using the global `x`).